# PHP If conditions

Tags: php

I'm embarrassed.

I have three functions to check what the current logged in user is:

```
public function isAuthor(User $user)
{
    return $user->getId() === $this->getDestination();
}

public function isSupervisor(User $user)
{
    return $user->getId() === $this->getFirstApprover();
}

public function isSecondApprover(User $user)
{
    return $user->getId() === $this->getSecondApprover();
}
```

And then I want to add a condition inside my actions to check if the user is any of the above mentioned three. If he is not one of them access should be denied. A user can sometimes be more than one of them, but mostly only one of the three.'

I was first thinking of something like this, but obviously it can't work

```
if (!$object->isAuthor($this->getUser()) || !$object->isSupervisor($this->getUser()) || !$object->isSecondApprover($this->getUser())) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException();
}
```

What will be the best way to check if a user is one of them? Should I create a whole new function?

Should I use something like this:

```
if (!$object->isAuthor($this->getUser())) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException();
} elseif (!$object->isSupervisor($this->getUser())) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException();
}
```

Can I please have some thoughts and input from others? Because I'm now really confused. *Still a newbie here*

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||` in your first if condition trial

Comment: *"but obviously it can't work"* - Why not? You've merely mixed up your boolean logic. You want `is not X AND is not Y AND is not Z`, in other words *"is none of these"*. Currently you are expressing *"if any one of these is false"*…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic will work, it's just a "reverse" boolean logic, complicated to follow. It has a bug, Use && instead of ||.

**One alternative**:

```
if ( ! (  $object->isAuthor($this->getUser()) || 
        $object->isSupervisor($this->getUser()) || 
        $object->isSecondApprover($this->getUser() ) ) 
{
    throw new AccessDeniedException();
}
```

**Another alternative**, you could write a function in the "Object" class:

```
public function hasAccessLevelX( User $user )
{
    return in_array( $user->getId(), [
            $this->getDestination(),
            $this->getFirstApprover(),
            $this->getSecondApprover()
    ] );
}

if ( !$object->hasAccessLevelX( $this->getUser() ) ) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException();
}
```

I would use the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

**Common Function**

```
public function userLogin(User $user)
{
    $userId = $user->getId();
    if($userId == $this->getDestination() || 
       $userId == $this->getFirstApprover() || 
       $userId == $this->getSecondApprover())
    {
        return TRUE;    
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

**Use/Call of common function**

```
if ($object->userLogin($this->getUser()) == FALSE) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException();
}
```

Comment: Can the one who down voted please say why? I thought this looks good.

Comment: Thanks... I am also worried why down voters didnt write proper comment and reason. Thanks again. Accept if useful to you. @JackCoolen

Comment: That's bad naming and return values. What does "userLogin is 0" *mean*? Nothing much. It's a magic number with implied meaning. That should be `userIsLoggedIn` and return a `boolean`, that's self explanatory.

Comment: The else statement is not necessary. You can just `return true` if the if-statement doesn't `return false`

Comment: Now the function is returning `false` **or `null`** and `== FALSE` will always match.